# How can I make a number of images scale proportionally based on its container height?

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to figure out how to do this. I have 3 images, all in different but specific sizes that will scroll horizontally within a container (container will have `overflow: hidden`. That container should take up as much space as possible between two other divs and I'm doing that with `flex-grow: 1`, and the container looks good.

However, those images, how can I make sure they resize and keep proportions based on that container height, based on viewport height?

I know maximum size the images can be in both width and height.

Please have a look at my example here: https://fvsu2.csb.app/

As you can see, the images wont resize at all if the container they are within is getting a lower height than the image itself...? It just stops, and the bottom part goes below viewport.

Is this even possible?

Comment: Please post your relevant "*[mcve]*" code in your question - here, on the site - that way we, and future visitors, can see the code and hopefully understand how they might apply the solution to your problem to their own code.

Comment: But I added a link to code sandbox?

Comment: Yes, you did. But the [mcve] code has to be here in your question to guard against the removal, reorganisation, failure or closure of that external site.

Comment: Okay. Will add it asap. Please if you are able to look at the example for now, if you have any suggestions!

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by ‘keep proportions based on the container height based on viewport height‘? Do you want each image to show completely, no cropping, whatever its aspect ratio or do you want the container space completely covered each time, which may mean some images get cropped to fit?

Comment: @AHaworth I would say, to make sure the images show everything but their height is based on the container height, and width should then be “auto”. Is that enough as explanation?

Comment: So at some aspect ratios they will overflow the container at the left and right sides?

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding in what I would like to achieve. Simply I want the “middle” container’s height to dictate the relative height of the images, and the images should keep their aspect ratio. You see what I mean?

Answer (score 0):

U want your cardImage to be height:auto width:100%, what u have now is in reverse.

Comment: Please look at my last comment on my initial question

Answer (score 0):

you could try this:

1. do not set height for images, it will distort the image
2. set container height to auto
3. set images width to 100%

example:

```
.container{height: auto}
.container .images{width: 100%}
```

in case of overflow,
set this

```
.container{height: auto; overflow: hidden}
```

but the images will not overflow out of the container if you set the images width to width: 100% and make sure the width of the container is in px or use bootstrap to set the width of the container e.g.

```
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12"></div>
```

for the container, with this the images will never overflow the container

Comment: For some image aspect ratios and container size this may mean the image overflows the container, I’m not sure whether this is what is required or not.

Comment: alright, in case of overflow, you can add the code in the editted version of my reply

Comment: OK, so overflow is acceptable. I was going to suggest object-fit but it sounds as though that isn’t needed. I’m a bit surprised that cropping is OK, but if it is then it doesn’t matter that making width 100% may result in top and bottom of imageS disappear. Does this mean you have resolved the problem?

Comment: you will be the one  to set the maximum height you want of the container in case of pictures that have a longer height, then those images height will not pass the maximum height while still in their aspect ration, you could set the  css max-height  of the container with e.g. max-height: 100px, and the behavior of the second picture is normal.